# Entity Framework Core Runtime database Creation and Migration inside WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core

I have an issue with migrations in EF Core. From what I understand Migration allows me to modify/update database model with the ability to move between old and newer versions of the database. The problem is My WPF app Creates database on the fly. I'm able to create Database ('Code First Approach') and the migration Table is there:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxuPf.png)

So my question is Can I do something like Add-Migration / Update-Database from C# code. So when somethings happen in the future for example I will have to add some columns or tables - I can update my app and my app will handle migration. Is there a way?

Comment: What type of database?  Can you modify database first instead of classes?

Comment: I use code First on mysql. And when I modify the structure there is no error but when I try to use some for example table that I added later - I get error about table not exists.

Comment: You are using Entity which uses a mapping to associate the database with c#.  When you modify the database you need to refresh the mapping file.  See following : https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/9708189/how-do-you-update-an-edmx-file-with-database-changes-?force_isolation=true

Comment: But I dont have that file and from what I see its for model-first and than I can edit it, right? And It don't allow me to do it on a fly/runtime but only in editor which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with WPF applications, but with a C# API I was able to add that functionality at startup. `context.Database.Migrate()` is the command to apply migrations programmatically.

This is the function that I used in my API Startup file:

```
    private void UpgradeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<PrimeDbContext>();
            if (context != null && context.Database != null)
            {
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used context.Database.Migrate() but it just create database. I cannot modify it later. If I add a table and I want to used it I get error that table was not created even when I used Database.Migrate.